# What is the easiest way to factorize $x^2-xy-2y^2-x-4y-2=0$ without using any software?

Tags: factoring

I already tried to create a small group between any variables like x and y to make it distributiveable. But nothing happened, and I cannot continue to the desired form.

Here's my attempt:
I think I need to factorize $x^2-xy-2y^2$ such that I get $(x-2y)(x+y)$ , but then I got the bad form like $(x-2y)(x+y)-(x+4y+2)$ so that I cannot continue to find a better form to perform distributive property here.

Is there any theorems or any ideas to factorize such that equation like this?

Thanks

Comment: What I would do is multiply two terms with arbitrary coefficients and then equate them to see if there is a solution like so: $$x^2 - xy - 2y^2 - x - 4y - 2 = (ax + by + c)(dx + ey + f).$$ There are some quick simplifications you can make.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to start with where you want to end up and reverse engineer to get the answer. This is one such case.

Comment: thanks for the hints, I think I will try it by my self. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A genral method for the quadratic of $x,y$:

Take it as a quadratic of $x$ and treat $y$ as constant, then
$$x^2-x(-y-1)-2y^2-4y-2=0$$ $$ \implies x=\frac{(y+1)\pm\sqrt{(y+1)^2+4(2y^2+4y+2)}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{(y+1)\pm 3(y+1)}{2}$$
You get two linear  factors here.

Answer (score 0):

As also suggested in the comments, we can proceed as follows

$$(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)=adx^2+bey^2+(ae+bd)xy+(af+cd)x+(bf+ce)y+cf$$

and then

- $ad=1$
- $be=-2$
- $ae+bd=-1$
- $af+cd=-1$
- $bf+ce=-4$
- $cf=-2$

and we can try to solve starting with $a=d=1$ or $a=d=-1$.

---

As an alternative by $y=ax+b$ we obtain

$$x^2-xy-2y^2-x-4y-2=$$

$$=x^2-ax^2-bx-2a^2x^2-4abx-2b^2-x-4ax-4b-2=$$

$$=(1-a-2a^2)x^2+(-b-4ab-1-4a)x+(-2b^2-4b-2)=0$$

which requires

- $1-a-2a^2=0 \implies a=-1 \quad a=\frac12$
- $-2b^2-4b-2=0 \implies b=-1$
- $-b-4ab-1-4a=0$ always true for $b=-1$

therefore two factors are

- $c(y+x+1)$
- $d(2y-x+2)$

with $c$ and $d$ constants easy to find.